# Progressbar for between 2 dates with php and css

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

i want a progressbar to show the how much time completed between 2 given days, most probably i got answer but it doesn't work on some cases

Styles:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #progressbar div
    {
      background-color: #99cc66;
       width: 50%; 
       height: 20px;
       border-radius: 10px;

    }
    </style>
```

case 1:  working  code

```
<?php
$date1 = strtotime("2014-09-05 11:44:01");
$date2 = strtotime("2014-09-07 12:44:01");
$today = time();


$num = $today - $date1;
$den = $date2 - $date1;
$percentage = ($today - $date1) / ($date2 - $date1) * 100;
?>
<?php if($percentage<100 && $percentage>=0){ ?>
<div id="progressbar" style="border: 1px solid ; border-radius: 10px;">
<div style="width: <?php echo $percentage; ?>%;"><span><?php echo round($percentage,2); ?>%</span></div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

case 2: not working

if i have to change the datetime format to 24 hours, i can't see the prgoressbar the $percentage is in negative values

```
<?php
$date1 = strtotime("2014-09-05 11:44:01");
$date2 = strtotime("2014-09-07 23:44:01");
$today = time();


$num = $today - $date1;
$den = $date2 - $date1;
$percentage = ($today - $date1) / ($date2 - $date1) * 100;
?>
<?php if($percentage<100 && $percentage>=0){ ?>
<div id="progressbar" style="border: 1px solid ; border-radius: 10px;">
<div style="width: <?php echo $percentage; ?>%;"><span><?php echo round($percentage,2); ?>%</span></div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

i want this progressbar work with the even 24hour format, any clue on this?

Comment: What's the difference between the code in case 1 and case 2? I don't see it?

Comment: @LinkinTED check the $date1 and $date on each cases

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you, Im turning blind I guess, I still don't see it :/

Comment: on the 1st case it is just `$date1 = strtotime("2014-09-05 11:44:01");
$date2 = strtotime("2014-09-07 12:44:01");` and on 2nd `$date1 = strtotime("2014-09-05 11:44:01");
$date2 = strtotime("2014-09-07 23:44:01");`  `2014-09-07 23:44:01` 23:44:01 this is the difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just try using this logic:

```
if ($today < $date1)
{
    $perentage = 0;
}
else if ($today > $date2)
{
    $percentage = 100;
}
else
{
    //$date2 - $date1 = 216000 (difference between 2 days)
    // Logic
    // 216000          => 100%
    // $date2 - $today =>   x%
    // x = ($date2 - $today) / 2160
    //$percentage = ($date2 - $today) / 2160
    //As the OP mentioned the difference can vary so here's how to do it for any diff.
    $percentage = ($date2 - $today) * 100 / ($date2 - $date1);
}
```

Comment: actually i don't want for the 2 days, i want it by 2 given dates, the days differences may vary

Comment: Still no problem. You always know that the difference between $date2 and $date1 is 100% :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should define timezone as well.

Then you can use:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$date1 = strtotime("2014-09-04 17:44:01". " UTC");
$date2 = strtotime("2014-09-07 23:44:01". " UTC");
```

Comment: thanks, however if use like `date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$date1 = strtotime("2014-09-05 11:44:01". " UTC");
$date2 = strtotime("2014-09-07 11:44:01". " UTC");` this is also not working even use with timezone

Comment: The `$date1` is a future date - `echo` these dates:
`echo "$date1\n\t$date2\n\t\t$today\n\n";`
`echo "$num\n\t$den\n\t\t$percentage\n\n";`
Then you will see that these values are lower than 0.

Answer (score 0):

## Using jquery

just include

`http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/dark-hive/jquery-ui.css`

## [- Demo Fiddle 2day](http://jsfiddle.net/tePc3/22/)

## [- Demofiddle 10second](http://jsfiddle.net/tePc3/24/)

It will show 100% after 2 days ;)

[image: jquery timer]

---

**html**

```
<span style="display: block;" class="percent"></span>

<div class="progressbar-count" value="100%"></div>
```

**javascript/jquery**

```
jQuery.ease = function (start, end, duration, easing, callback) {
    // Create a jQuery collection containing the one element
    // that we will be animating internally.
    var easer = $("<div>");

    // Keep track of the iterations.
    var stepIndex = 0;

    // Get the estimated number of steps - this is based on
    // the fact that jQuery appears to use a 13ms timer step.
    //
    // NOTE: Since this is based on a timer, the number of
    // steps is estimated and will vary depending on the
    // processing power of the browser.
    var estimatedSteps = Math.ceil(duration / 13);

    // Set the start index of the easer.
    easer.css("easingIndex", start);

    // Animate the easing index to the final value. For each
    // step of the animation, we are going to pass the
    // current step value off to the callback.
    easer.animate({
        easingIndex: end
    }, {
        easing: easing,
        duration: duration,
        step: function (index) {
            // Invoke the callback for each step.
            callback(
            index, stepIndex++, estimatedSteps, start, end);
        }
    });
};
$(".progressbar-count").each(function () {
    var $self = $(this),
        targetVal = parseInt($self.attr("value"));
    $self.progressbar({
        value: 0
    });
    $self.prev(".percent").text("0%");
    $.ease(0, targetVal, 172800000, "swing", function (i) {
        $self.progressbar("option", "value", parseInt(i));
        $self.prev(".percent").text(parseInt(i) + "%");
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, where i can input my dates ?